# Rileys From The Grave

Tags: riddle, affix-riddle

> My prefix is a veggie,
>
> My infix is... though, it's on the interblags *[citation: xkcd]*
>
> My suffix is to eat, in Spanish, in English, in Spanish,
>
> And altogether I am not GERMANE, but am GERMAN.

> My prefix is two,
>
> My infix, is, misspelled.
>
> My suffix is my country's, and?
>
> My whole speaks of spicy peppers and bullfighters.

> My prefix is another, but B->R,
>
> My infix is what I am, basically,
>
> My suffix is in off.
>
> Altogether, I am from... what was it... "Stars of Russkie"?

**What are we, in common?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of these riddles clues:

> the name of a famous deceased **composer** - specifically, **BEETHOVEN**, **BIZET** and **RACHMANINOFF**.

*My prefix is a veggie,*
*My infix is... though, it's on the interblags [citation: xkcd]*
*My suffix is to eat, in Spanish, in English, in Spanish,*
*And altogether I am not GERMANE, but am GERMAN.*

> Prefix: A **BEET** is a vegetable;
>  Infix: **THO** is Internet-slang for 'though';
>  Suffix: This line requires some back-and-forth between Spanish and English: EAT (English) is COME in Spanish, then COME in English is **VEN** in Spanish. (Thanks @xyldke in comments.)
>
>  Together (with overlap), BEET + THO + VEN = [Ludwig van **BEETHOVEN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_van_Beethoven) (1770-1827), a German composer.

*My prefix is two,*
*My infix, is, misspelled.*
*My suffix is my country's, and?*
*My whole speaks of spicy peppers and bullfighters.*

> Prefix: **BI** means 'two';
>  Infix: **IZ** is 'IS' misspelled;
>  Suffix: **ET** is 'and' in French.
>
>  Together (with overlap), BI + IZ + ET = [Georges **BIZET**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_Bizet) (1838-1875), the French composer of the opera [*Carmen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmen) which is set in Spain, with its connotations of spicy peppers and bullfighting.

*My prefix is another, but B->R,*
*My infix is what I am, basically,*
*My suffix is in off.*
*Altogether, I am from... what was it... "Stars of Russkie"?*

> Prefix: **RACH** is BACH (the name of yet another composer) with the 'B' becoming an 'R';
>  Infix: This composer was a **MAN**;
>  Suffix: Quite literally, **INOFF**.
>
>  Together, RACH + MAN + INOFF = [Sergei **RACHMANINOFF**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergei_Rachmaninoff) (1873-1943), a Russian composer born (according to [some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:People_from_Starorussky_Uyezd) [sources](https://adp.library.ucsb.edu/index.php/mastertalent/detail/102117/Rachmaninoff_Sergei)) in *Starorussky* Uyezd.

Comment: I think the prefix is just rot13(ira, orpnhfr (ra)rng -> (rf)pbzre -> (ra)pbzr -> (rf)ira. Gur tenzzne znxrf irel yvggyr frafr, fb V'z cebonoyl zvffvat fbzrguvat, ohg gur fgrzf znxr frafr naq gur jubyr va fcnavfu, va ratyvfu, va fcnavfu guvat fpernzf zhygvcyr genafyngvbaf gb zr)

Comment: @xyldke I did wonder something back-and-forth-translational like that, but it's the step where 'comer' in Spanish becomes 'come' in English that makes little sense to me. I agree that the first and last make a lot of sense though - just this problematic middle! :)

Comment: I got it now: All words should be in the imperative. Thus eat! -> ¡come! -> come! -> ¡ven!

Comment: Thanks @xyldke - makes sense :)

Comment: Btw "Stars of Russkie" clues his hometown, Starorussky (wikipedia is amazing for this, btw)

Comment: I'm actually stunned by your puzzle solving skills Stiv! How are you this fast and good???

Comment: Thanks for the compliment @DialFrost :) I hold my grandma entirely responsible - when I was a kid she used to buy me puzzle books but staple the answer pages together before she gave them to me: I had no option but to learn how to solve them without peeking!